# Should we dupe-close questions that are older than their duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

In my review queue I recently find a lot of old questions (> 2 years say) that are to be closed as duplicates. With most of them I agree in principle, but the relevant text when closing questions as duplicates says

> This question has been asked **before** and already has an answer.

where the emphasis is mine. The point is, in most of these cases that is strictly speaking not true, i.e. the question that is now in the review queue had been asked before the suggested duplicate.

I agree about the duplicate content and I do not want to advocate the strict reading of the rules here but rather gather some opinions from among us.

What triggered this question was [this post from Dec 2014](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39358/32134) which received an excellent (and even accepted) answer from @GayotFow only to receive it's first upvote from me one and a half years later. The [suggested dupe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34106/32134) here is slightly older (July 2014) and does not exactly fit the general situation I want to describe.

We had a related discussion [here on meta about questions that should be closed as off-topic.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/should-we-close-old-questions)

Comment: I think this was discussed on the main meta and the advice was something like, if there's a big difference in quality of answers, make the copy with the better quality answers the one that stays open and has the link pointing towards it; if in any doubt, go by age. Can't find it right now though.

Comment: [If Jon Skeet posts a duplicate question on StackOverflow, the original question will be closed as a duplicate.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/38765)

Comment: +1, can we get one of those sql whiz-bangs that measures it precisely?