# What to do with outdated questions?

Tags: discussion

[Should we close old questions?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1450/4188) dealt with old questions but this is a different topic: [What's the cheapest transport to get from Ataturk International aiport to the Taksim Square area of Istanbul?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/348/4188) is simply outdated. Ataturk airport is no more. Anyone stumbling on this question and missing or not knowing what Ataturk means another airport (and that's more and more likely with every passing year) would be misinformed. In my opinion it should be removed.

What do we think? Should this be a flag reason?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a historical lock would be appropriate? According to [this main meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631):

> ### What is a *historical lock*?
>
> A *historical lock* is a mechanism by which moderators can mark posts as historical artifacts.  Questions which are historically locked feature the following post notice:
>
> > **Locked.** This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.

> In addition to the post notice being prominently displayed, posts which are historically locked are "frozen in time": they cannot be voted on, flagged, answered, edited, bountied, or commented on (though [they can be favorited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307304/377214), and ♦ moderators can edit and comment; moderator edits to historically locked posts do not bump the posts). The visual appearance of the entire post is altered by removing the voting arrows from the question and all answers.

I'm not sure if this type of lock is available on all sites. Nevertheless, it seems like a good option because:

- The content isn't deleted, so there's a nice historical record.
- The content won't bump with recently active questions.
- Mods can leave a comment under or disclaimer in the question explaining why it has been locked.

---

Regarding questions about Ataturk Airport, there are [still some open (and non-locked) questions referring to that airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=ataturk+airport+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0+locked%3A0). Feel free to flag some of these for moderator attention if you've verified that they should be locked.

Comment: Yes I wanted to edit it to add a note but then I reconsidered because it would bump it :/

Comment: If you flag (moderator attention) and ask for a historical lock, your friendly local mod should do that for you. (No guaranty, as I am not your only mod.)

Comment: @Willeke in this case [there are quite a few](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=ataturk+airport+is%3Aquestion), might want to look through them yourself to see where a lock would be appropriate. :)

Comment: 61 posts is a lot for me to go through as well, certainly next to my work and normal moderating. Maybe some people can volunteer and flag 2 worst ones when they have time.

Comment: @Willeke added an updated link which excludes locked or closed questions. I guess there's no hurry, they probably don't get a lot of attention now anyway.

Comment: Many are done, I hope people will flag the ones still left that need closure.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in a comment on the first answer, flag for moderator attention and ask for closure for historical significance, but remember that mods do often not have the time or inclination to handle all tags in a bigger topic.